# Integrate Selenium Webdriver with Java-EE

Tags: java, selenium, jakarta-ee

I wish to make make my Selenium Webdriver scripts user friendly. 
Currently I'm creating my automation scripts using Selenium Webdriver with Test-NG framework. To Run the project I Run the xml file as Test-NG suite.

I possess basic knowledge of Java-EE. Is there any way to integrate these two?
Idea is to use Java-EE for running automation scripts and Test-NG framework for Test Reports.

Comment: JavaEE is a set of standards for an enterprise container, it is not some tool which you use to run scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just create a web application using any of the web technology like Struts/Spring MVC/Angular
2. Using Maven add Selenium dependencies
3. Start automating your tests
4. Create some UI - And using Java/TestNG call your selenium keywords/test-cases - 'You can generate your testNG.xml at run time, based on UI inputs'.

Please let me know if you need any other details.